# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, visualization, pygal

I practice writing some code to get top repositories of Python from GitHub and this is the error I see:

[image]

this is the code which causes above stated error:

```
import requests 
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS


path = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'

r = requests.get(path)

response_dict = r.json()

# Explore information about the repositories.
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    plot_dict = {
        'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'label': repo_dict['description'],
        'xlink': repo_dict['html_url'],
    }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)

my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=LCS)
# Make visualization.
my_config = pygal.Config()
chart = pygal.Bar(my_config, style=my_style)


my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=LCS)
chart.title = 'Most-Starred Python Projects on GitHub'
chart.x_labels = names

chart.add('', plot_dicts)
chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```

Can you help me with this please. Thank you

Comment: Please use code formatting for tracebacks. They are highly unreadable in quote format

Comment: I apologize but I just added a pic of tracebook, SO asks me provide more information after code formatting the traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a `None` value somewhere where a string is expected, and the traceback seems to show it is the `label` value.

Try to change this:

```
plot_dict = {
    'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
    'label': repo_dict['description'],
    'xlink': repo_dict['html_url'],
}
```

To this:

```
plot_dict = {
    'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
    'label': repo_dict['description'] or "",
    'xlink': repo_dict['html_url'],
}
```

Comment: Thank you @olinox14, it works fine now. 
How do I get better in reading traceback? those tracebacks won't helped me at all if you didn't point out this issue.

Comment: `line 233, in decorate metadata['label'])` this is hard to understand at first sight

Comment: The traceback was indeed difficult to read, but what you could do in such situation is to use a debugger and add a breakpoint on the problematic line. This should lead you to the solution 95% of the time...

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your code. It looks like some links have no label (so they are of type None) [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM5N6.png). `_compat.py` then tries to invoke the method `decode ("utf-8")` on a None-Type, which leads to the corresponding crash.

I recommend all entries in plot_dicts that have no label to be labeled with an empty string like shown in the code below. The code below works for me.

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS


path = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'

r = requests.get(path)

response_dict = r.json()

# Explore information about the repositories.
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    plot_dict = {
        'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'label': repo_dict['description'],
        'xlink': repo_dict['html_url'],
    }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)

my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=LCS)
# Make visualization.
my_config = pygal.Config()
chart = pygal.Bar(my_config, style=my_style)


my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=LCS)
chart.title = 'Most-Starred Python Projects on GitHub'
chart.x_labels = names

# preprocess labels here
def f(e):
    if e['label'] is None:
        e['label'] = ""
    return e
plot_dicts = list(map(f, plot_dicts))


chart.add('', plot_dicts)
chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```

Maybe you find a better way to map the list but that definitely works.

Comment: As I've just seen, you already have your answer. Well, that's it